# Unix scripting whoami/$USER not working as desired

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Hi I have the script as below.

```
if [[ 'whoami' -eq "test" ]]; then
    echo "test user" 
else
    echo "Not a test user" 
fi
```

This is returning test user even if my user is not text. It would be great if someone can pin point my silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

`-eq` is for integer testing.
e.g.:

```
kent$  [[ "a" -eq  "b" ]] && echo "y" || echo "n"                                                                                                                           
y
kent$  [[ 34 -eq  35 ]] && echo "y" || echo "n"                                                                                                                             
n
```

try:

```
kent$  [[ "a" == "b" ]] && echo "y" || echo "n"                                                                                                                           
n
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using single quotes in place of backticks:

```
if [[ `whoami` -eq "test" ]]; then   # Not 'whoami'
```

For improved readability (and easier nesting, if applicable), use

```
if [[ $(whoami) -eq "test" ]]; then
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just like this:

```
if [[ `whoami` == "test" ]]; then  # Not 'whoami' -eq
    echo "test user" 
else
    echo "Not a test user" 
fi
```

don't use single quote and '-eq'